# How to frame mongo db query with specific user id and array of subdocument field not equal to null

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, database

Consider the following example. From this, I want to frame a query in mongo db which has UserId: "test" and "Orders.PaidDateTime" not equal to null

I should get the following result.

Example:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5953b6873a45f70afc6ce3a2"),
    "CreatedDateTime" : ISODate("2017-06-28T14:00:39.192Z"),
    "UserId" : "test",
    "Orders" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("59560f2b844faa0ff4933aa6"),
            "CreatedDateTime" : ISODate("2017-06-30T08:43:23.666Z"),
            "PaidDateTime" : null
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("59564ba3a046041364c24de4"),
            "CreatedDateTime" : ISODate("2017-06-30T13:01:23.290Z"),
            "PaidDateTime" : null
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("59564f168be0720e1c346857"),
            "CreatedDateTime" : ISODate("2017-06-30T13:16:06.072Z"),
            "PaidDateTime" : ISODate("2017-06-30T13:16:29.000Z")
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5953b6873a45f70afc6ce3a2"),
    "CreatedDateTime" : ISODate("2017-06-28T14:00:39.192Z"),
    "UserId" : "test",
    "Orders" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("59560f2b844faa0ff4933aa6"),
            "CreatedDateTime" : ISODate("2017-06-30T08:43:23.666Z"),
            "PaidDateTime" : null
        }
    ]
}
```

Result:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5953b6873a45f70afc6ce3a2"),
    "CreatedDateTime" : ISODate("2017-06-28T14:00:39.192Z"),
    "UserId" : "test",
    "Orders" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("59564f168be0720e1c346857"),
            "CreatedDateTime" : ISODate("2017-06-30T13:16:06.072Z"),
            "PaidDateTime" : ISODate("2017-06-30T13:16:29.000Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can someone please help on this query?

Answer (score 0):

Use $ne opertaor **https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/**
db.inventory.find( { UserId: "test" , "Orders.PaidDateTime" : { $ne: null } } )

Comment: It's returning no records.

Comment: I tried the following, even this is returning zero records

db.getCollection('User').find({"UserId": "test", "Orders.PaidDateTime": {$exists: true, $ne: null}})

Please let me know if you've any other solution to this...

Thanks